# Declaring and using global variables in a custom admin menu item

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, variables

I'm working on a custom review system. In this project in need to have and ID passed from a callback function which is declared below:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_edit_review', 'edit_review_callback' );
function edit_review_callback() {
  check_ajax_referer( 'edit-review-function', 'security' );

    $GLOBALS['review_edit_id'] = $_POST['table_id'];
    echo $GLOBALS['review_edit_id'];
    die();
}
```

That function is called like this:

```
            $(".edit_review").click(function() {

                    //Select the right id for selecting right row
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var td = tr.find('td:eq(0)').text();

                    //Create data to send withs security nonce
                    var data = {
                            action: 'edit_review',
                            security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce_edit; ?>',
                            table_id: td
                    };

                    //Send ajax-request
                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                            alert( 'Response: ' + response );
                    });

                    var url = "<?= get_site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sub_menu_item_two_review'?>";
                    $(location).attr('href',url);

    });
```

I want to set these global variables to use them in my custom menu item.
Which is declared like this:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'review_page_slug',
    'review_menu_page',
    'Edit review',
    'manage_options',
    'sub_menu_item_two_review',
    'edit_review_render'
);
```

Some where in here i want to use the variable:

```
function edit_review_render() {}
```

Ways I have tried to declare global variables;

1. global $review_edit_id; $review_edit_id = value;
2. $GLOBALS['review_edit_id'] = $_POST['table_id']; //As visible in the code below;

Ways I have tried to read variables:

1. global $review_edit_id; var_dump($review_edit_id); //Same as using the databas with global $wpdb;
2. var_dump($GLOBALS['review_edit_id']);
3. echo $GLOBALS['review_edit_id'];

I'm new to wordpress and have been working with it for about 4 weeks by now. I think its fun but I've been stuck on this part since the day before yesterday. Any help woud be much apriciated(and sorry for the big amount of code.).